# gocode binary not found spacevim

Tags: macos, go, file-type, neovim, spacevim

### Summarize the Problem

I want to make the following error clear.

Spacevim was installed using neovim. Later, in Spacevim, a go layer was added.

If you input anything after running gofile, the following error occurs.

I think it is an error that the go-code binary file could not be found. However, the $GOPATH/bin/gocode file exists. I don't know why.

### Describe What you've tried

I tried deplete.nvim, gocode, all. However, while trying, I kept facing new errors and couldn't proceed any further.

### Show some code

[image]

Comment: And is $GOPATH/bin in your PATH? What happens when you run `type gocode` in your terminal?

Comment: I have this problem on `nvim` on a new installation.

I attempted to install `gocode` from https://github.com/nsf/gocode but then ran into `[deoplete] gocode panicked use :messages / see above for error details.`
`nsf/gocode` says to switch to https://github.com/mdempsky/gocode which says to use https://github.com/stamblerre/gocode which says to use https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls

I'll update with an answer when I figure it out.

Comment: https://github.com/stamblerre/gocode claims it is in maintenance mode but `go get -u github.com/stamblerre/gocode` worked for me. See https://github.com/deoplete-plugins/deoplete-go/issues/134#issuecomment-435436305

Comment: I solved it.
This is the go binary file was not installed in the path.
So, copying the go binary file to the path worked fine.